# How to add delombok code compileKotlin task

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, lombok, gradle-kotlin-dsl

*Disclaimer:* This is a Gradle specific and not specific to lombok or Kotlin.**This works with Maven** but I am struggling with how to achieve the same with Gradle (with my half-knowledge).
How can I selectively provide sourceSets for lombok with `src/main/java` and Kotlin compiler with `${project.buildDir}/generated/sources/delombok/java/main`?

**Problem details and Use-case**: I call Kotlin from Java and some Kotlin files use Java classes that are annotated with Lombok. So the idea is (which I followed in Maven as well) is to delombok first to generate sources -> then point Kotlin to use delombok generated sourceSets to prepare end results.
The problem is, when I do this, it appends this sourceSets to `src/main/java` (which leads to compile failure)

```
compileKotlin {
    dependsOn(delombok)
    sourceSets.main {
        java.srcDirs("${project.buildDir}/generated/sources/delombok/java/main")
    }
}
```

When I use `setSrcDirs` instead of `srcDirs` like below, lombok is not able to pick-up java files from `src/main/java` (this is strange as I only have set it up in `compileKotlin` and not top-level sourceSets)

```
compileKotlin {
    dependsOn(delombok)
    sourceSets.main {
        java.setSrcDirs(listOf("${project.buildDir}/generated/sources/delombok/java/main"))
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you literally have `ourceSets` in your Gradle file, or is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: oh sorry it's paste error. let me correct

Answer (score 1):

I've used Kotlin in Lombok-enabled Java projects without any issues in the past.
Things may have changed, but the only thing I recall doing is declaring Lombok as a compile-time dependency and annotation processor:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8")
}
```